# Access Object by variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically I need to get a value out of a variable and insert it into a sequence.
I generally have no clue how to put this into words since I'm dutch but I hope you understand my question

```
var channelname = msg.channel.name;
"description": `${config.ticketlist.channelname.ticketmessage}`,
```

(Ofcourse highlights from the code)

But when I want to get the ticketmessage it doesn't work since **channelname** is not actually defined in my json file. It should be like ticket-001. But now its gonna search for **channelname** but not for the actual ticket name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use computed paths with bracket syntax. Use

```
"description": `${config.ticketlist[channelname].ticketmessage}`,
```

instead.

Comment: For some reason it doesnt seem to work but when I change the channelname to a string it does work. I use this line : "var channelname = newticketchannel.name;" to define the channelname. newticketchannel is bascily the message channel. When I console.log it it just perfectly returns the ticket name but it doesn't wanna select it in the object.

Comment: is it not a String by default?

Comment: The docs say it's string so it should be a string i'm pretty sure. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=name

Comment: What happens if you log `config.ticketlist`? Does it have a key named after your channel name?

Comment: { 'ticket-032':
   { ticketnumber: 32,
     ticketchannelid: '..',
     ticketowner: 'ImperialisticCobra',
     ticketmessage: 'hoi' } }

Basicly I use the name of the object to get the ticketmessage.

The "ticket-032" is basicly the channel name.

Comment: By the way the error that it returns is: "(node:9388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticketmessage' of undefined"

Comment: Which means, that there is no `ticketlist[channelname]`

Comment: Ahhhhh I got it. Thank you man. I basicly want to read it before its done inserting it into the JSON file. Thanks for the help buddy.